# What does pre incrementing array object (++frequency[i]; ) mean?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class ArrayStudentPoll {
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
       // array of survey responses
       int responses[] = { 1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6, 
         10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6, 
         4, 8, 6, 8, 10 };
       int frequency[] = new int[ 11 ]; // array of frequency counters

       // for each answer, select responses element and use that value 
       // as frequency index to determine element to increment
       for ( int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
          ++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];


       System.out.printf( "%s%10s\n", "Rating", "Frequency" );

       // output each array element's value
       for ( int rating = 1; rating < frequency.length; rating++ )
          System.out.printf( "%6d%10d\n", rating, frequency[ rating ] );
   }
}
```

This is the code I'm looking at it in my project.

Everything I understand but the part `++frequency[i];` where frequency is an array and not a number? What exactly it is doing there? They wrote comments but still, I didn't get them.

Here is the result I am getting out of it

```
Rating Frequency
     1         2
     2         2
     3         2
     4         2
     5         5
     6        11
     7         5
     8         7
     9         1
    10         3
```

Answer (score 3):

`++frequency[responses[answer]]` pre-increments the `responses[answer]`'th element of the `frequency` array.

It's equivalent to

```
frequency[responses[answer]] = frequency[responses[answer]] + 1;
```

BTW, using post-increment (`frequency[responses[answer]]++`) will give the same result in this program, since the return value of the increment operator is not used by this code.

Comment: But what is the logic of that loop ? Can you explain it ?

Comment: @javadevabhi It counts how many times each number appears in the `responses` array. After the loop `frequency[i]` will contain the number of times `i` appears in the `responses` array.